# How can I make my layout more responsive?

Tags: html, css

Ok guys I have styled this very well, but there are a few quirks! I have tried everything and it looks great/good as a responsive site, but there are some issues. I cannot get the .therapy section to look the way I want it to. Full page it hugs the left margin, but looks good with my media queries. My question is how do i get it to look good on full page and be responsive as well. Thanks and hugs. I would like the margins to come in a few px and look like it is not using all the white space available. please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css" type="text/css"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<style>
body{
    background-color: #f1f0d1;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    overflow: auto;
}
h1, h2, h3{
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5%;
    color: #878e63;
}
p{
    padding: 2%;
    color: #878e63;
}
img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1020px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #fefbe8;
    border: 1px solid #878e63;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#callout {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #878e63;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#callout p {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0.1% 5% 0 0;
    color: #f1f0d1;
}
#callout p a {
    color: #f1f0d1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    width: 96%
    min-height: 125px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 90px;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #878e63;
    width: 15%;
}
nav ul li a {
    background-color: #f1f0d1;
    display: block;
    padding: 5% 12%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #878e63;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li.active a {
    background-color: #878e63;
    color: #f1f0d1;
}
.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #878e63;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #878e63;
}
.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
.left-col {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    margin:  1% 1% 1%;
}
.sidebar: {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
.therapy {
    /*float: left;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /*padding: 1%;*/
}
.section{
    width: 29%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
footer{
    background-color: #878e63;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer p, footer h3 {
    color: #f1f0d1; 
}
footer p a {
    color: #f1f0d1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
ul li img {
    height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body{
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid #878e63;
        border-right: 0px solid #878e63;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #878e63;
        border-left: 0px solid #878e63;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 8px 0;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .left-col, .sidebar, .section {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<!-- redo all images on the page and style with css3-->
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="callout">
            <p>Call us at <strong>727-555-5555</strong></p>
        </div><!--end callout div-->
        <header>
            <!--need ne image--><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/massagelogo.png" alt="Massage" title="Massage by ?"></a>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <!--make active later--><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <!--make active later--><li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <!--make active later--><li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
            <!--make active later--><li><a href="#">Consult</a></li>
            <!--make active later--><li><a href="#">Consult</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </nav>
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/massagebanner.png" alt="need new" title="new">
            </div><!--close banner-->
            <!--fix w css--><center><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/three_sayings.png" alt="need new" title="new"></center>
            <section class="left-col">
                <!--use h2 tag and css--><p style="text-indent: 50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie pellentesque at convallis eros. Ut luctus ex eget tempor scelerisque. Praesent blandit velit eu turpis aliquam pellentesque. Cras vel erat eget ligula sollicitudin commodo.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie pellentesque at</p>
                <p style="text-indent: 50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie pellentesque at convallis eros. Ut luctus ex eget tempor scelerisque.</p>
            </section>
            <aside class="sidebar">
                <div class="therapy">
                <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/therapist.jpg" alt="need new" title="new">
                </div><!--close therapy div-->
            </aside>

        <div class="section">
            <h3>Text Text Text Text</h3>
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/private.png" alt="need new" title="new">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risus In non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie</p>
            </div><!--close section div-->
            <div class="section">
            <h3>Text Text Text Text</h3>
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/sauna-steam.png" alt="need new" title="new">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risusIn non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie</p>
            </div><!--close section div-->
            <div class="section">
            <h3>Text Text Text Text</h3>
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/retreat.png" alt="need new" title="new">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non fringilla risusIn non fringilla risus. Quisque sollicitudin iaculis nunc, ultricies fringilla ex malesuada eu. Quisque a augue in mauris molestie</p>
        </div><!--close section div-->
        <!--fix w h2 and css --><center><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/ease.png" alt="need new" title="new"></center> 

        <footer>
            <div class="section">
                <p>Text Text Text</p>
                <p><strong>727-555-5555</strong><br>
                123 Main St<br>
                Anywhere, FL 33770<br>
                blank@blahblah.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <p>Connect with us!</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook1.png" alt="need new" title="new"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/googleplus.png" alt="need new" title="new"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png" alt="need new" title="new"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube1.png" alt="need new" title="new"></a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/plant.png" alt="need new" title="new">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div><!--end wrapper div-->
        <p>&copy;  2014.</p><!--margin 0 auto this-->

</body>

</html>
```

I know it is a lot, but I am stuck, I think my math is off. Please advise me how I can resolve and thank you.

Comment: Why not using framework and save time and nerves :) for example, Bootstrap.

Comment: Please view in jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: I know it is something I am overlooking, but having a bit of trouble. Please any help is"desired"

Comment: This is a valid question with expectations from professionals better than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to improve the use of white space, you need to make a concept at first. For example your text is currently above a huge image. Unter this huge image there are three smaller boxes.

So you could say in full screen you want the image and text next to each other. This is done by adding the following to the media query you want the text and image to appear next to each other:

```
aside.sidebar {
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Then you need to insert

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Below the closing `</aside>` tag! You have inserted something like this for your sidebar in line 106 with `.sidebar:`, which is a "broken code" because of the `:` after your css class.

This is a quite simple example, but works for all kinds of pages. If you need further explanations feel free to ask, this is a "quick help" copy & paste solution.

Best regards,
Marian.

Answer (score 1):

I found a typo (an unecessary colon):

```css
.sidebar: {          /*here*/
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```